# 2-step Runge Kutta method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

I just started studying RK method of order 2.
I want to know that, " RK method of order 2 and 2 step RK method are same or not?"

Comment: It's not usually called the 'two step RK method', rather, the 'two _stage_ RK method'.

Comment: You can easily construct 2-stage RK methods that only have order $1$. I think it starts with order $6$ that there are no p-stage methods of order $p$.

Comment: @Mattos y_n+1 = y_n + 1/2(K0+K1)
is this a 2 step method or 3 step method?

Comment: Two function evaluations = two stages.

Answer (score 0):

Steps/stages = number of function evaluations.

Order = accuracy of the approximation.

The usual RK2 requires two evaluations and the error is $O(h^2)$ ($h =$ step size.)